# How to only show bottom border for segmented control in xcode

Tags: swift, xcode, uisegmentedcontrol, ibaction

I have the following code

```
extension UITextField {
    
    func setPadding() {
        let paddingView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 10, height: self.frame.height))
        self.leftView = paddingView
        self.leftViewMode = .always
    }
    
    func setBottomBorder() {
        
        self.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
        self.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 0.0, height: 1.0)
        self.layer.shadowOpacity = 1.0
        self.layer.shadowRadius = 0.0
    }
    
}

    extension UISegmentedControl {
        func removeBorder(){
            let backgroundImage = UIImage.getColoredRectImageWith(color: UIColor.white.cgColor, andSize: self.bounds.size)
            self.setBackgroundImage(backgroundImage, for: .normal, barMetrics: .default)
            self.setBackgroundImage(backgroundImage, for: .selected, barMetrics: .default)
            self.setBackgroundImage(backgroundImage, for: .highlighted, barMetrics: .default)

            let deviderImage = UIImage.getColoredRectImageWith(color: UIColor.white.cgColor, andSize: CGSize(width: 1.0, height: self.bounds.size.height))
            self.setDividerImage(deviderImage, forLeftSegmentState: .selected, rightSegmentState: .normal, barMetrics: .default)
            self.setTitleTextAttributes([NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.gray], for: .normal)
            self.setTitleTextAttributes([NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor(red: 67/255, green: 129/255, blue: 244/255, alpha: 1.0)], for: .selected)
        }

        func addUnderlineForSelectedSegment(){
            removeBorder()
            let underlineWidth: CGFloat = self.bounds.size.width / CGFloat(self.numberOfSegments)
            let underlineHeight: CGFloat = 2.0
            let underlineXPosition = CGFloat(selectedSegmentIndex * Int(underlineWidth))
            let underLineYPosition = self.bounds.size.height - 1.0
            let underlineFrame = CGRect(x: underlineXPosition, y: underLineYPosition, width: underlineWidth, height: underlineHeight)
            let underline = UIView(frame: underlineFrame)
            underline.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 67/255, green: 129/255, blue: 244/255, alpha: 1.0)
            underline.tag = 1
            self.addSubview(underline)
        }

        func changeUnderlinePosition(){
            guard let underline = self.viewWithTag(1) else {return}
            let underlineFinalXPosition = (self.bounds.width / CGFloat(self.numberOfSegments)) * CGFloat(selectedSegmentIndex)
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.1, animations: {
                underline.frame.origin.x = underlineFinalXPosition
            })
        }
    }

    extension UIImage {

        class func getColoredRectImageWith(color: CGColor, andSize size: CGSize) -> UIImage{
            UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(size, false, 0.0)
            let graphicsContext = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()
            graphicsContext?.setFillColor(color)
            let rectangle = CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width: size.width, height: size.height)
            graphicsContext?.fill(rectangle)
            let rectangleImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
            UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
            return rectangleImage!
        }
    }

    
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBAction func segmentedControl(_ sender: UISegmentedControl) {
        print("djfdd")
        sender.changeUnderlinePosition()
    }
```

When I run the project the segmentedControl is normal and no changes have been applied. I have been stuck with this issue and and I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong. I am also not getting any error messages.

**EDIT**

The way I created the segmented control was adding it in storybard, I did not give it a class. Then to create the action I simply left clicked and dragged it into my viewcontroller.swift. I also have not added any constraints.

Comment: You're declaring the segmentedControl in the segmentedControl's action move that to viewDidLoad and add it as subview to view for a start and see if it works.

Comment: When I declare the segmentedControl outside of the action i get the error message: Use of unresolved identifier 'segmentedControl' and what exactly do you mean by add it as a subview?

Answer (score 0):

You're creating a new instance of `UISegmentedControl` in the `segmentedControlDidChange` and applying the changes. This won't apply the changes to the existing `SegmentedControl`. Here's want you've to do to apply those changes to the existing `UISegmentedControl`. Modify the `segmentedControlDidChange` method as follows:

```
@IBAction func segmentedControlDidChange(_ sender: UISegmentedControl) {
    sender.changeUnderlinePosition()
}
```

Comment: When I add that code it creates a a new segmented control although doesn't apply any of the changes I want

Comment: Add the entire code related to segmented control in you view controller in the question.

Comment: I added the sender.changeUnderlinePosition() but still nothing

Comment: Explain in your post on how you created that segmentedControl and action.

Comment: I just added it at the end

Comment: can you check if the changes are applied once the segmentedControl action is triggered? PS: Also, after adding the code that I've posted,

Comment: I just tested it and the changes are being applied, I put a simple Print method and it showed in the console. clearly the action is working any ideas what to do now?

Comment: You need to control drag from the segmented control in your storyboard to the view controller file and drop it to add action and outlet.

Comment: I have added it as an action by doing that

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/216587/discussion-between-frankenstein-and-appledeveloper123).